# Query Optimization for Combination Calculation

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables which are as below:

Table 1 for having different Combinations of variables (non-repetitive):

```
name1   name2   name3
var1    var10   var11
var1    var10   var12
var1    var10   var13
```

Table 2 for the scores of each combination of Id (Say a person):

```
Id  name    score
1   var1    0
1   var10   0
1   var11   0
1   var12   0
1   var13   1
1   var14   0
1   var15   0
1   var16   1
1   var17   0
1   var18   0
1   var19   0
1   var2    0
1   var20   0
1   var3    0
1   var4    0
```

The above table has 20 such different ID score Combination and both of these tables have many records.

Now I wish to get the the distinct count of IDs of 2nd Table by using 1st Table combination of variable Characters.

Eg.

```
name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6 name7 name8 name9 name10 name11  Total Score
 var1 var10 var11 var12 var11 var3  var2  var7  var6  var11   var4    55
 var1 var10 var12 var13 var2  var2  var1  var8  var4  var20   var5    44
 var1 var10 var13 var14 var1  var1  var5  var9  var9  var6    var7    33
```

This way distinct count of IDs provide individual combinations score if any one of the combination has Score=1 in the 2nd Table.

I use the below query for join:

```
select top 1000  name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9, name10, name11, reach=(select count(distinct(Id)) from temp3 where temp3.score=1 and (
temp3.name in ( name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9, name10, name11))), 
freq=(select sum(cast(score as tinyint)) from temp3 where temp3.score=1 and (
temp3.name in ( name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9, name10, name11)))
from ( SELECT name1=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name2=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name3=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name4=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name5=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name6=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name7=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name8=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name9=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name10=name, T.* from temp1 join (
SELECT name11=name from temp1
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9 and name<>name8 and name<name8
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9 and name<>name8 and name<name8 and name<>name7 and name<name7
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9 and name<>name8 and name<name8 and name<>name7 and name<name7 and name<>name6 and name<name6
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9 and name<>name8 and name<name8 and name<>name7 and name<name7 and name<>name6 and name<name6 and name<>name5 and name<name5
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9 and name<>name8 and name<name8 and name<>name7 and name<name7 and name<>name6 and name<name6 and name<>name5 and name<name5 and name<>name4 and name<name4
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9 and name<>name8 and name<name8 and name<>name7 and name<name7 and name<>name6 and name<name6 and name<>name5 and name<name5 and name<>name4 and name<name4 and name<>name3 and name<name3
) T on name<>name11 and name<name11 and name<>name10 and name<name10 and name<>name9 and name<name9 and name<>name8 and name<name8 and name<>name7 and name<name7 and name<>name6 and name<name6 and name<>name5 and name<name5 and name<>name4 and name<name4 and name<>name3 and name<name3 and name<>name2 and name<name2
)t order by reach desc, freq desc
```

This way 11 different combinations are done and the query takes long to execute.

Please provide a faster approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the following will make your query faster, but it will at least make it cleaner.  What I do in these situations when I inherit somebody's denormalized table, is make the data normalized by using a CTE to transform the data.  At the very least it'll make the query more maintainable, and sometimes results in improved performance.

In this case I'll transform table1 into a table with just a row id and a name.

```
WITH table1WithIds AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name1, name2, name3) [RowId], name1, name2, name3
    FROM table1
)
, namesRelational AS (
    SELECT RowId, name1 [name] FROM table1WithIds
    UNION
    SELECT RowId, name2 [name] FROM table1WithIds
    UNION
    SELECT RowId, name3 [name] FROM table1WithIds
)
SELECT t1.name1, t1.name2, t1.name3, SUM(t2.score)
FROM namesRelational nr
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = nr.name
INNER JOIN table1WithIds t1 ON t1.RowId = nr.RowId
GROUP BY t1.name1, t1.name2, t1.name3
```

The first cte, table1WithIds, creates a unique id for each row.  If you already have one on table1 and omitted from your example, you can skip this step.  This will also go along way to improving the efficiency of the query if you do.

The second cte, namesRelational, does the work of transforming table1 into something normalized.

The query itself is dead simple once you have the transformed table.  One caveat to this approach is if table1 has the same values but in different order (i.e. in one row you have 'var1', 'var2', 'var3' and in the other 'var3', 'var2', 'var1') then you will get a result for each duplicate instance.

Comment: Used CTE and that solved the issue, although did not use the exact query you suggested, but now the query executes really fast.